# 2d vector says class does not have member named push_back

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

```
ManageShips::ManageShips(vector< Spaceship <Item> > itemShip,
                     vector< Spaceship <Person> > personShip,
                     vector< Item > itemCargo,
                     vector< Person > personCargo){

  m_itemShips = itemShip;
  m_personShips = personShip;
  m_items = itemCargo;
  m_person = personCargo;

}

void ManageShips::LoadItemShip(){

  int numberItemShips = m_itemShips.size();

  int numberOfItems = m_items.size();

  int itemCount = 0;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < numberItemShips ; i++){

    int shipFull = 0;

    double shipWeight = 0;


    while ( shipFull == 0){

      while (itemCount < numberOfItems){

    if ((m_items[itemCount].GetWeight() + shipWeight ) > m_itemShips[i].GetCapacity()){
      shipFull = 1;
    }
    else {
      m_itemShips[i].push_back(m_items[itemCount]);
      shipWeight = m_items[itemCount].GetWeight() + shipWeight;
      itemCount = itemCount + 1;
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a 2d vector of type spaceships which holds data of type items.
I am trying to add item objects into the first spaceship but it gives me an error saying class spaceship item does not have a member named push_back

it's this line and I dont see what's wrong with it.

```
  m_itemShips[i].push_back(m_items[itemCount]);
```

help is appreciated.

Edit: if youre gonna downvote me atleast give me a reason please. I am just asking a question.

Comment: `m_itemShips[i]` looks to be a `Spaceship <Item>`, not a `std::vector`.  `Spaceship` may or may not have a `push_back` method. More cannot be said without a [mcve] or guesswork. Off topic, look into using the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: Spaceship is a templated class. it does not have a push_back method but ManageSupply class creates a vector of type spaceship<items> so it should have access to push_back. i am not sure

Comment: "so it should have access to push_back" What push_back? You said there isn't one, that's your problem.

Comment: vectors in c++ have access to push_back method that is built into the vector library right?

Comment: `m_itemShips` is a `std::vector` and has a `push_back` method. `m_itemShips[i]` is a request to get the item at `i` from `vector` `m_itemShips`. The item at `i` is a `Spaceship <Item>`. You are calling `push_back` on the `Spaceship <Item>` at `i`, not on `m_itemShips`.

Comment: ok thanks i'll look into the member initialized list you recommended but is there any other way to add item to the vector?

Comment: As already pointed by " user4581301", m_itemShips is a vector, but its elements are not of vector type, so when you do m_itemShips[i], it points to type Spaceship, which is not a vector container, so push_back will fail if you are not implementing it in Spaceship

Comment: Not enough information to give you a good answer Nabil. Your goal is not clear. Are you trying to add items to the Spaceship?

Answer (score 0):

`m_itemShips` is a (presumably) a `std::vector< Spaceship <Item> >` and `m_items` is a `std::vector< Item >`.    (and you have given no information about what `SpaceShip` or `Item` are).

This means that `m_itemShips[i].push_back(m_items[itemCount])` requires `SpaceShip<Item>` to have a member function named `push_back()` that can accept an `Item`.

If `SpaceShip<Item>` does not have such a `push_back()` member function, that explains your error message.

Importantly, `SpaceShip<Item>` does not magically acquire a method named `push_back()` even if it has a data member of type `std::vector<Item>`.    If you want such a member function, you have to define it.